# How to view index view with records only for current user

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have tried many options and included them here.  Any option I've tried seems to produce some new error.

```
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        //var userId = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());

        //var requests = db.Requests.Where(m => m.UserId == userId); ;

        //var requests = db.Requests.Include(r => r.User);
        //return View(await requests.ToListAsync());

        //var userId = UserManager.FindById(User.Identity.GetUserId());
        //var requests = db.Requests.Where(m => m.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());
        //return View(await requests.ToListAsync());
        var requests = db.Requests.Include(e => e.User).Where(m => m.UserId == User.Identity.GetUserId());

        return View(requests);
    }
```

and my model

```
public class Request
{
    [Key]
    public int RequestId { get; set; }

    public string UserId { get; set; }

    [StringLength(128), MinLength(3)]
    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }

    public DateTime Date
    {
        get { return DateTime.Now; }
    }
    public string Ticket { get; set; }
}
```

I've finally figured out how to create records with the current user associated, but I can't view just these records associated to just the current user.

The error is

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: What errors are you getting? You have not shown your models so we can't possibly guess.

Comment: I have received quite a few errors, but I feel like there is some filter to view only the records associated to the current user and nothing beyond this is necessary.  I could easily be mistaken though.

Comment: So what error is your current query for `requests` giving you (what you have shown looks fine)?

Comment: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String GetUserId(System.Security.Principal.IIdentity)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: Thank you for the help by the way.

Comment: Prior to that line, add `string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();` and then change the query to `...Where(m => m.UserId == userID );`

Comment: You are the man!.  Repost and I'll give you the check mark.  Seriously thank you.  This has been such a big hole in my understanding.  Looking now, I'd tried this earlier but with userId instead of userID.  Capitialization did me in.  Thanks again

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assign the value of the current user to a variable first, and then use that value in the query

```
string userID = User.Identity.GetUserId();
var requests = db.Requests.Include(e => e.User).Where(m => m.UserId == userID);
return View(requests);
```